# Detecting how many colors an uploaded image has

Tags: php, colors

How can I detect how many colors an image has, adn then return the RGB or Hex values of those colors in PHP?  With the standard file formats... PNG, JPG, GIF etc.

**Sample image:**
[image]

**Used for:**
An online design tool which allows you to upload images for use in the designer.  I'm trying to reject all images with over 10 colors (or potentially reduce the colors?).  For images with less then 10 colors, I'm trying to return the Hex or RGB values of each color that is present (the more colors present, the more expensive the printing process).

Comment: Can you give an example of image? And the purpose of such code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$gd = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

$width = imagesx($gd);
$height = imagesy($gd);

$colors = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
{
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
    {
        $color = imagecolorat($gd, $x, $y);
        $hex = sprintf("0x%06x", $color);

        if(!in_array($hex, $colors))
        {
            $colors[] = $hex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is damn-slow, but I was posting the same solution :)

Comment: If I was trying to reject any image with over 10 colors, could I use a  more statistical method as opposed to pixel-by-pixel checking?

Comment: @Walker:  You would simply put this in a function and return `false` as soon as `count($colors) > 10`.  I don't believe that's the most optimal, but it's probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 0x0000e1
    [1] => 0x0000e0
    [2] => 0x0000e3
    [3] => 0x0000e2
   )//i am getting this type array contains values how can i know 0x0000e1 is which color

Comment: how can i know which number signifies which color.